# Naudio fails to fully read WMA, OGG, and AC3 audio files

Tags: .net, naudio, wma

I am unable to fully read the audio contents (all bytes) of a WMA file using NAUDIO.

Here are 2 example WMA audio files that fail...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-CxTIOmFCwiPvcoMm_iwl-dybOv680bp
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uirNcYok1BYtL0trgQZHhqHAywW14rOe

My code (simplified)...

```
Dim myReader As New NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader(stringAudioFileURL)
Dim myAudioData As Byte(myWaveReader.Length - 1)
myReader.Read(myAudioData, 0, myReader.Length)
If myReader.Position <> myReader.Length Then
    Throw New System.Exception("Failed to read to end of file!")
End If
myReader.Dispose()
```

With both of the example files provided, the AudioFileReader fails to read to the end (all bytes) of the file (AudioFileReader.Length).

I can open and successfully play both files in the Windows Media Player.

Based on further testing...The same problem occurs in NAUDIO with OGG, and AC3 formatted audio files.

Thanks!  Also...Hello and thanks to Mark Heath for NAudio!...A great audio toolset for MS Windows!

Comment: I was going to suggest the issue is due to not calling `myReader.Read()` in a loop since it overrides [`Stream.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read), but I tried your code with the first file and the first call to `Read()` returns `47562752` and the second returns `0`, so that's as far as it will read.  I am familiar with neither NAudio nor the structure of WMA files, but I'm thinking perhaps those `16208` bytes at the end are the audio container itself or otherwise non-audio data.

Comment: I originally used a loop to do the read...like this...While iBytesLeftToRead > 0
            iBytesToRead = System.Math.Min(iBytesLeftToRead, readBuffer.Length)
            samplesReadPrior = samplesRead
            samplesRead += myWaveReader.Read(readBuffer, 0, iBytesToRead) 
            Array.Copy(readBuffer, 0, myAudioData, samplesReadPrior, iBytesToRead) 
            iBytesLeftToRead = CType(myWaveReader.Length - myWaveReader.Position, Integer)
        End While    'But my loop went infinite when it couldn't read the last 16208 bytes of the file.

Comment: I used `Dim bytesRemaining = myReader.Length Dim lastReadCount = myReader.Read(myAudioData, 0, bytesRemaining) While lastReadCount > 0 bytesRemaining -= lastReadCount lastReadCount = myReader.Read(myAudioData, myReader.Length - bytesRemaining, bytesRemaining) End While`.  The loop exits properly since the condition is based on the result of `Read()`, but it doesn't end up reading any more data than the original loopless version.